# Change For Loop to Recursive Method

Tags: java, data-structures

Could you please explain to me how to change this for loop to recursive I know what recursive is but I have been unable to get the number of stars to print correctly with the code as it only printing the first line of stars.

Any guidance would be appreciated,

Here's my current code:

```
static void printLine(int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Homework question! :)

Comment: Which part of that (admittedly odd) requirement are you struggling with? Do you understand what recursive methods are? If yes, what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: You need to identify the base case to determine when recursive calls stop. You also need to define the recursive case, i.e. what happens when it is not the base case. The recursive case will print a star `*` and call the `printStars()` with `lines - 1`. The base case will print the last star or just do nothing, depending on how it is defined. I'm not going to write the code for you. Recursion can be tricky, but this example is nice and simple for an introduction.

Comment: What exactly is the question? To print n stars in a row? To print n rows of n stars?

Answer (score 2):

Googling "how to convert for loop to recursion," there's a similar answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a), and an article with an example [here](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceIterationWithRecursion.html).

This is a pretty big hint but the basic idea is that your arguments store the current loop state.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    // ....
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
private static void PerformAction(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            // Do something
            PerformAction(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should be able to Google pretty easily, make sure you try finding the answer yourself before asking the community. I don't mind answering questions like this, but I've found that you don't really learn anything if you ask first and look later.

```
private static void printStars(int n)
{

if (n>0){
system.out.println("*");
printStars(n-1);
        }
}
```